# Query works in SQL Server, but not in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

The following SQL statement works in SQL Server, but not in Oracle:

```
UPDATE example
SET ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM example) + rownum
```

Oracle complains:

> SQL command not properly ended

Why is this code works perfectly fine in SQL Server, and not in Oracle? Please help.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow jennifer, is `ID` the primary key for table `example`?

Comment: This does work in Oracle. The update changes the rows' IDs (something that should never be done; a row's ID should always stay the same; it's its ID after all). It takes all rows and numbers them continuously starting with the number that follows the minimum ID in the table. It does not consider the current order, though. This means, you can get from the rows 5/oldest, 7/middle, 9/newest to the rows 6/newest, 7/oldest, 8/middle for instance.

Comment: Why were you expectig it to work? SQL Server and Oracle implement the SQL Standard in different ways, plus each one has a myriad of non-standard enhancements as well. They are quite different animals.

Answer (score 2):

You must be wrong, stating that this works in SQL Server, but not in Oracle. It must be vice versa, because Oracle does have a `ROWNUM` function, while SQL Server has not:

- Oracle: [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=55f8d39ab74bc95e4adf2d3ab9d11d7f)
- SQL Server: [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eba2c5c1ade931dbc1331dc2dcc7ecb1)

For SQL Server you need `ROW_NUMBER` to create the row numbers and `UDATE FROM` in order to be able to access that row number in the update:

```
UPDATE example
SET id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM example) + rownum
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rownum FROM example) e;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5e0c61f5f2bd599191b439a45bcb5866

Comment: thank you for your post but the code is not working on Oracle. I don't know why. ID column is my primary key.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error message? If so, which? Are you getting incorrect results? If so, in what way incorrect? What Oracle version are you using?